# Where should you close the database on the android activity lifecycle?

Tags: android, database, android-activity

Should you close it in the onDestroy() or in the onStop() functions?

Answer (score 4):

I personally prefer to close the Database as soon as I am done using it, keeping an database open is similar to keeping an `FileStream` open which I don't think is a good Idea. Depending upon your use you should call `close();` on your database asap.

**UPDATE**

Regarding to you original question, it is OK to close database on `onDestroy()` event.

Answer (score 1):

It is best to close the data base in the `onPause()` method at the latest. After that, it is possible that the OS will kill off the process without notice if it needs resources, potentially damaging your data base. Definitely don't defer this to `onStop()` or `onDestroy()`. From [the docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/activities.html):

> `onPause()` is the last method that's guaranteed to be called before the process can be killed—if the system must recover memory in an emergency, then `onStop()` and `onDestroy()` might not be called.

An alternative is to move all your data base access to a Service or a ContentProvider, which have their own separate lifecycles and rules for interaction with the OS.

Answer (score 0):

I never explicitly close a SQLite database.

I always use a class that extends `SQLiteOpenHelper` and have methods to do whatever I need and never keep a permanent reference to the database itself. Once the `SQLiteOpenHelper` goes out of scope, the database references are cleaned up.

YMMV but it comes down to how you design your app - I've been working with SQLite databases for a lot of years on Windows platforms well before I started programming for Android and I've yet to have a corrupted database.

Answer (score 0):

You must close your database connection as soon as you dont need that connection any more and also for clodsing that connection you must call close().